# What are the coefficients of $x^2+2\in(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}4)[x]?$

Tags: polynomial-rings

If $$(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}4) = \{\bar{0}, \bar{1}, \bar{2}, \bar{3}\}$$

How can it be possible that $x^2+2 \in (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}4)[x]$?

In other words, how can the 2 value in $x^2+2$ be expressed as a member of ($\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}4)[x]$ if each element in ($\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z4})[x]$ is a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2+2$ here actually means $\bar 1\cdot x^2+\bar 2$.

I know it is **super** uncomfortable to accept the fact (fate) that *sets* can be used as *elements* of a group.  But in the case of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, indeed $sets$ are used as elements.

If you still feel very uncomfortable about this, try to use {a,b,c,d} to substitute $\{\bar 0,\bar 1,\bar 2,\bar 3\}$ with same operations.  Then the polynomial above can be written as $bx^2+ax+c$, and we can even perform $a+b=b$ and $b+b+b+b=a$.

Just treat them as notations so that you will feel more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients are $1$ and $2$... elements of ${\mathbb Z}_4$...

$1$ is the coefficient of $x^2$; $2$ the constant coefficient ...
For each element (set) of $\mathbb  Z/\mathbb Z4=\mathbb Z_4$, one can use any *representative* of that set, or residue class...

Thus $1=5=9=13=17...$ etc...  all represent the same element...

Similarly,  $2=6=10=14=18=\dots$ and so on.

There are $4$ such infinite sets, or elements, in $\mathbb Z_4$...

So, for instance,  $5x^2+6$ is, or represents, the same polynomial here...